# put text along with unix command then feed to a file

Tags: awk, tcsh

In the `tcsh` shell on Unix, I would like to print the folder name together with the number of files that I searched, then feed it to a file.

However I just manage to find the number of count then write to a file, not sure how to attach the folder name along.

`my_folder.txt` contains a list of directory names such as:

```
dir_1
dir_2
dir_3
```

```
foreach a (`cat my_folder.txt`)
find ./netlists/spice/${a}.sp -newermt '8/16/2022 0:00:00' | wc -l  >check_latest.txt
end
```

Now that above code will output just the number of files, such as:

```
10
5
4
```

But I look to print out something like this:

```
dir_1   10
dir_2   5
dir_3   4
```

May I know how to achieve this?

Comment: I've never tried writing a tcsh script for [the common reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not) so idk but isn't ```foreach a (`cat my_folder.txt`)``` an antipattern in tcsh just like ```for a `cat my_folder.txt` ``` or similar would be in a bourne derived shell like bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but this might be what you want:

```
foreach a (`cat my_folder.txt`) echo "$a " $(find ./netlists/spice/${a}.sp -newermt '8/16/2022 0:00:00' | wc -l)  >check_latest.txt; end
```

Personally, I'd split it onto multiple lines to make it more readable:

```
foreach a (`cat my_folder.txt`)
do
  count=$(find ./netlists/spice/${a}.sp -newermt '8/16/2022 0:00:00' | wc -l)
  echo "$a $count"
done >check_latest.txt
```

Comment: What shell are you writing this for? Note that you dropped `end` from the first command in the later loop and instead introduced `do ... done` and a `sh`-style command substitution using `$(...)`, while keeping `foreach` which is not from standard `sh`.  You also moved the redirection out of the loop without remarking on it.

Comment: @Kusalananda, that code would work in `zsh`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Which one, the first or the last or both? It would be good if the original user could clarify what shell they are using.

Comment: @Kusalananda, second. The first would need to have the `;end` removed unless the `cshjunkieloops` option is enabled (and from a functionality (as opposed to syntax) PoV, the redirection moved out of the loop at least).

Comment: Thanks Steve, and everyone's help this far. I try with Steve'code, however it doesn't works for me. I get 'Illegal variable name.' for Steve code #1. For code #2, my environment seem doesn't allow 'do' cmd.

Comment: They are using `tcsh`.

Comment: The question didn't initially say that this was tcsh (although the question seems now to have been edited it now to clarify this).
The syntax was in the original question was legal zsh, and I assumed that it was written for that and ended up using some bash-style syntax that isn't valid in csh-style scripting languages 
Rather than confuse things by editing the first answer I'll post a new one

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this in tcsh:

```
foreach a (`cat my_folder.txt`)
  set count=`find ./netlists/spice/${a}.sp -newermt '8/16/2022 0:00:00' | wc -l`
  echo "$a $count"
end
```

I'm not sure what you intend the redirection to do. If you actually want the results to end up in a file you need to do the redirection at the end of the loop:

```
foreach a (`cat my_folder.txt`)
  set count=`find ./netlists/spice/${a}.sp -newermt '8/16/2022 0:00:00' | wc -l`
  echo "$a $count"
end > check_latest.txt
```

Comment: You seem to have added a second answer that's almost the same as [your first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713918/100397). Was that intentional? Or did you mean to [edit your other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/713918/edit)?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
m=open('/home/praveen/folder.txt','r')
for i in m:
    ko=os.listdir(i.strip())
    co_file=len(ko)
    print "{0} {1}".format(i.strip(),co_file)
```